# In Couchdb, if I have a key with empty value in some of the documents?

Tags: key, couchdb, document, key-value, string

A question about the best practice in Couchdb...
If I have a key that in some documents missing any value, should I leave it as empty string as following

```
"myKey":""
```

or should I skip it and not having myKey when it is empty? In the latest case if fetching value for myKey gives no-key-found would be equal to myKey is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the big things about couchdb(and other no sql databases) is that they give you the ability to have a flexible schema. This means that you don't have to adhere to any pre- enforced constraints on your data. So I don't think there is any reason for you to have an empty key in the document.

With reference to couchdb

1. Couchdb makes generous use of disk space. It is recommended to keep the number of chanracters in the keys at a minimum. So adding empty keys will only consume more disk space.
2. If you fetch a document by it's _id couchdb will give you back the result as you stored it. If you stored `myKey` as an empty string you will get back a document containing an empty `myKey`
3. If you are building view on  a key you should always check if the key is present in a document or not and emit only if it is present. Like so

`function(doc){if(doc.myKey) emit(doc.myKey,doc._id);}`

This way couchdb will create an index only for relevant documents.  I think it's best if you don't store an empty key in a document at all.